# pydantic: AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute

Tags: python, pydantic

I am running into some problems with loading .env file contents in config file as app config attributes, I am using pydantic-0.7.1 with python 3.6.7 running the apps for validating type and existence of vars. project structure is laid out as follows

cat .env

```
APP_PROJECT_NAME_TOPICS='["streaming.topic"]'
```

cat `__main__.py`

```
from project_name_consumer.app import create_app, app_cli


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app_cli(create_app)
```

cat `__init__.py`

```
__version__ = '1.0.0.0'
```

cat app.py

```
from typing import  List
from collections import MutableMapping
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from os import getcwd, path
from time import sleep
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseSettings
from argparse import ArgumentParser

class BaseConfig(BaseSettings):

    def __init__(self, prefix='', **kwargs):
        self.__config__.env_prefix = prefix
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


    def dict(self, prefix=''):
        return {
            key[len(prefix):]: value
            for key, value
            in self
            if key.startswith(prefix)
        }


class AppBaseConfig(BaseConfig):

    name: str = 'app'
    version: Optional[str] = None


    @property
    def app_name(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def app_version(self):
        return self.version

class App(MutableMapping):

    def __init__(self, config=AppBaseConfig, config_prefix='APP_'):
        self._load_dotenv()
        self.config = config(prefix=config_prefix)
        self.state = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.state[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.state[key] = value

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.state[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.state)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.state)

    def _load_dotenv(self):
        cwd = getcwd()
        filepath = path.join(cwd, '.env')
        if path.exists(filepath):
            print('Loading dotenv from %s', filepath)
            load_dotenv(filepath)

    def run(self, **kwargs):
        run_app(self, **kwargs)

def run_app(app, loop=None, force_shutdown_delay=5.0):
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        app.run()

class ProjectAppBaseConfig(AppBaseConfig):
    project_url: str = ''
    project_cert: str = None

class ProjectApp(App):

    def __init__(self, config=ProjectAppBaseConfig):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.session = None

class Config(ProjectAppBaseConfig):

    app_name: str = 'project-name-consumer'
    project_name_topics: List[str]


def create_app():
    app = ProjectApp(config=Config)
    for uri in app.config.project_name_topics:
        print(uri)

    return app


def app_cli(app_factory):
    parser = ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('-e', '--envfile', help='load dotenv file')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.envfile:
        load_dotenv(args.envfile)

    if isinstance(app_factory, App):
        app = app_factory
    else:
        app = app_factory()

    app.run()
```

cat setup.py

```
from os import path, walk
import re
from setuptools import find_packages, setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_py import build_py as _build_py
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import sysconfig

def open_file(filepath, mode='r'):
    here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))
    full_path = path.join(here, filepath)
    return open(full_path, mode)


def find_version(package):
    with open_file('{}/__init__.py'.format(package)) as f:
        return re.findall(r"^__version__ = '([^']+)'\r?$", f.read(), re.M)[0]


def find_requires():
    with open_file('requirements.txt') as f:
        return [line.strip() for line in f]

NAME = 'minimal_example'
VERSION = find_version('project_name_consumer')
PACKAGES = find_packages()
REQUIRES = find_requires()
EXCLUDE_FILES = [
    'project_name_consumer/__init__.py',
    'project_name_consumer/__main__.py',
]
class build_py(_build_py):

    def find_package_modules(self, package, package_dir):
        ext_suffix = sysconfig.get_config_var('EXT_SUFFIX')
        modules = super().find_package_modules(package, package_dir)
        filtered_modules = []
        for (pkg, mod, filepath) in modules:
            if path.exists(filepath.replace('.py', ext_suffix)):
                continue
            filtered_modules.append((pkg, mod, filepath, ))
        return filtered_modules



def get_ext_paths(root_dir, exclude_files):
    """get filepaths for compilation"""
    paths = []

    for root, dirs, files in walk(root_dir):
        for filename in files:
            if path.splitext(filename)[1] != '.py':
                continue

            file_path = path.join(root, filename)
            if file_path in exclude_files:
                continue

            paths.append(file_path)
    return paths

setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    packages=PACKAGES,
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=REQUIRES,
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        get_ext_paths('project_name_consumer', EXCLUDE_FILES),
        compiler_directives={'language_level': 3}
    ),
    cmdclass={
        'build_py': build_py
    }
)
```

python traceback is as follows

```
$ python3 -m project -e .env



INFO:app:Loading dotenv from .env
...
AttributeError: 'Config' object has no attribute 'project_name_topics'
```

I am using automate.sh for redoing repeated efforts

cat automate.sh

```
START_TIME=$(date +%s)
deactivate
rm -rf build
rm -rf dist
rm -rf venv 
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install Cython
pip install wheel
pip install -r requirements.txt
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
python setup.py bdist_wheel
pip install  dist/minimal_example-1.0.0.0-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl
python -m project_name_consumer
END_TIME=$(date +%s)
echo "script took $(($END_TIME - $START_TIME)) seconds..."
```

cat requirements.txt

```
python-dotenv==0.8.2
pydantic==0.7.1
```

$ minimal_example tree

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── automate.sh
├── project_name_consumer
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── app.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
```

Comment: You forgot to mention that your env var name does not match the field name and that you are customizing the `env_prefix` at runtime. That last part is potentially the root of the problem and if you **really** need to do it you probably will have better chances of getting help if your example is [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have tried to put in a minimal example please check